# weekly and monthly CRON Jobs

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created a Snowflake two tasks like the two below, and they havent worked so far.

1// should run at the beginning of each week at 5 am CET time

```
Create or replace task WEEKLY_jOB
warehouse =compute_wh
schedule = 'USING CRON 0 5 * * 1 CET'

AS

INSERT INTO ... ;

ALTER TASK WEEKLY_jOB RESUME;
```

---

2// should run at the beginning of each month at 5 am CET time

```
Create or replace task MONTHLY_JOB
warehouse =compute_wh
schedule = 'USING CRON 0 5 1 * * CET'

AS

INSERT INTO ...;
```

ALTER TASK MONTHLY_JOB RESUME;

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by "haven't worked"? Did they run but not do what you expected; did they run but not at the time you expected? When you resume them when are they showing as their next scheduled run?

Comment: @NickW, for the third week the scheduled weekly job didnt run at all and i had to run it manual.

Comment: it shows scheduled: USING CRON 0 5 * * 1 CET

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you run "select *
  from table(information_schema.task_history())
  order by scheduled_time;" does it show in the SCHEDULED_TIME, NEXT_SCHEDULED_TIME, etc. columns? Does it show that it is scheduled as you expect, does the STATE show it ran successfully?